# Basic Web Server Problem - Debian 10 & Apache2 - Hosting two Sites with self signed SSL certificates

Tags: apache, ssl, debian, certificate, apache2

Working on a project where the aim is to host a company's public website and an intranet site for staff. I've managed to get the public site running with an SSL certificate however the intranet site won't resolve to the domain name I have set. I am using apache 2. I believe the problem may be with the fac that both sites are on port 443? I'm a beginner so realize that more info will be needed. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

if you own a wildcard certificate (or multi-domains certificate), you may use several vhosts listening to the same IP address/https port, and both vhosts use the same certificate (listening on all interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to consider:

- Two web services both requiring the same kind of protocol, i.e. TCP on 443, cannot occupy the same port. But you could have some stream using UDP on 443 while at the same time running Apache2 on 443.
- Apache2 documentation is not universally identical between different Linux distributions. I've wasted so many hours following others advice, but I later learned that many of the instructions I was trying to follow did not specifically work for my distro. It is vitally important that you look for docs released in 2017-2019 for your specific OS otherwise you will lose entire weeks trying to fix a server.

As you've probably realized, configuration settings are not all in the same place. Depending on your administration requirements, some common sources of pain and frustration are:

1. `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` <- Many things go in here (look them up)
2. `/etc/hosts` <- Any reserved public IP's go in here
3. `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` <-Default listens on port 80, but can use an SSL module to secure client requests and server responses
4. Working with the `a2enmod` command
5. `/etc/apache2/sites-available/<thing>.conf` files
6. Using `a2enmod` with `/etc/apache2/sites-available/<thing>.conf`

Here are the best sources of info:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/apache-basics-installation-and-configuration-troubleshooting

Good luck!